# method overloading vs optional parameter in C# 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, overloading, optional-parameters

which one is better? at a glance optional parameter seems better (less code, less XML documentation, etc), but why do most MSDN library classes use overloading instead of optional parameters?

Is there any special thing you have to take note when you choose to use optional parameter (or overloading)?

Comment: Yes I am aware about that question, but it was asked before C# 4.0 was released and became widespread. and I have more questions (see the question details)

Comment: "why do most MSDN library classes use optional parameters instead of overloading?" - did you mean this the other way around? I'm not aware of any BCL classes that use optional parameters.

Comment: yup sorry i mean the other way around. sorry, edited

Answer (score 84, accepted):

One good use case for 'Optional parameters' in conjunction with 'Named Parameters' in C# 4.0 is that it presents us with an elegant alternative to method overloading where you overload method based on the number of parameters.

For example say you want a method `foo` to be be called/used like so, `foo()`, `foo(1)`, `foo(1,2)`, `foo(1,2, "hello")`. With method overloading you would implement the solution like this,

```
///Base foo method
public void DoFoo(int a, long b, string c)
{
   //Do something
}  

/// Foo with 2 params only
public void DoFoo(int a, long b)
{
    /// ....
    DoFoo(a, b, "Hello");
}

public void DoFoo(int a)
{
    ///....
    DoFoo(a, 23, "Hello");
}

.....
```

With optional parameters in C# 4.0 you would implement the use case like the following,

```
public void DoFoo(int a = 10, long b = 23, string c = "Hello")
```

Then you could use the method like so - Note the use of named parameter -

```
DoFoo(c:"Hello There, John Doe")
```

This call takes parameter `a` value as 10 and parameter `b` as 23.
Another variant of this call - notice you don't need to set the parameter values in the order as they appear in the method signature, the named parameter makes the value explicit.

```
DoFoo(c:"hello again", a:100)
```

Another benefit of using named parameter is that it greatly enhances readability and thus code maintenance of optional parameter methods.

Note how one method pretty much makes redundant having to define 3 or more methods in method overloading. This I have found is a good use case for using optional parameter in conjunction with named parameters.

Comment: All those who are going to use this approach - FYI you cannot change the name of parameters going forward if you use named parameters in caller, unless changing it in each caller (which is simple refactoring if all the reference are in same solution, but not if you use it as a library in other project).

Having said that, changing parameter name is always considered a breaking change anyhow (even if not using named parameters!)

Answer (score 63):

Optional Parameters provide issues when you expose them publicly as API. A rename of a parameter can lead to issues. Changing the default value leads to issues (See e.g. here for some info: [Caveats of C# 4.0 optional parameters](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2010/05/18/caveats-of-c-4-0-optional-parameters.aspx))

Also, optional params can only be used for compile-time constants. Compare this:

```
public static void Foo(IEnumerable<string> items = new List<string>()) {}
// Default parameter value for 'items' must be a compile-time constant
```

to this

```
public static void Foo() { Foo(new List<string>());}
public static void Foo(IEnumerable<string> items) {}
//all good
```

#### Update

Here's some additional reading material when a constructor with default parameters [does not play nicely with Reflection](https://web.archive.org/web/20140815160502/http://blog.coverity.com/2013/09/11/c-bug/).

Comment: The fact that the CALLING site has to have the defaults injected is definitely an issue for a public API.  If only we could get an optional parameter variant that is actually syntactic sugar for creating the overloads (while still keeping the existing one around for things like COM Interop).

Comment: Regarding renaming the parameters, this is already an issue regardless of the use of optional parameters or overloaded methods.  The consumer can specify a named parameter and renaming the variable will break the compile.

Comment: Link broken again...use the non-beta Wayback Machine link and it works.  https://web.archive.org/web/20140815160502/http://blog.coverity.com/2013/09/11/c-bug/#.WqvD6-jwaUk

Answer (score 53):

I believe they serve different purposes. Optional parameters are for when you can use a default value for a parameter, and the underlying code will be the same:

```
public CreditScore CheckCredit( 
  bool useHistoricalData = false,  
  bool useStrongHeuristics = true) { 
  // ... 
}
```

Method overloads are for when you have mutually-exclusive (subsets of) parameters. That normally means that you need to preprocess some parameters, or that you have different code altogether for the different "versions" of your method (note that even in this case, some parameters can be shared, that's why I mentioned "subsets" above):

```
public void SendSurvey(IList<Customer> customers, int surveyKey) {  
  // will loop and call the other one 
} 
public void SendSurvey(Customer customer, int surveyKey) {  
  ...  
}
```

(I wrote about this some time ago [here](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2009/08/optional-parameters-and-method.html))

Comment: For my money, this is the best answer. You're the only one to make the distinction of what the method body does. It makes perfect sense that if the method body is the same, then use optional params, but if the method body will vary based on the params, then use overloads.

Comment: perfect explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

This one almost goes without saying, but:

Not all languages support optional parameters. If you want your libraries to be friendly to those languages, you have to use overloads.

Granted, this isn't even an issue for most shops. But you can bet it's why Microsoft doesn't use optional parameters in the Base Class Library.

Comment: what happens if you use a library with an optional parameter from a language that does not support it (ex. C# 2.0)?

Comment: C# 2.0 ignores the "optional parameter" flag, and treats all parameters as required. So every call site has to provide a value for every parameter.

Answer (score 11):

Neither is definitively "better" than the other.  They both have their place in writing good code.  Optional parameters should be used if the parameters can have a default value.  Method overloading should be used when the difference in signature goes beyond not defining parameters that could have default values (such as that the behavior differs depending on which parameters are passed, and which are left to the default).

```
// this is a good candidate for optional parameters
public void DoSomething(int requiredThing, int nextThing = 12, int lastThing = 0)

// this is not, because it should be one or the other, but not both
public void DoSomething(Stream streamData = null, string stringData = null)

// these are good candidates for overloading
public void DoSomething(Stream data)
public void DoSomething(string data)

// these are no longer good candidates for overloading
public void DoSomething(int firstThing)
{
    DoSomething(firstThing, 12);
}
public void DoSomething(int firstThing, int nextThing)
{
    DoSomething(firstThing, nextThing, 0);
}
public void DoSomething(int firstThing, int nextThing, int lastThing)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Optional parameters has to be last. So you can not add an extra parameter to that method unless its also optional. Ex:

```
void MyMethod(int value, int otherValue = 0);
```

If you want to add a new parameter to this method without overloading it has to be optional. Like this

```
void MyMethod(int value, int otherValue = 0, int newParam = 0);
```

If it can't be optional, then you have to use overloading and remove the optional value for 'otherValue'. Like this:

```
void MyMethod(int value, int otherValue = 0);
void MyMethod(int value, int otherValue, int newParam);
```

I assume that you want to keep the ordering of the parameters the same.

So using optional parameters reduces the number of methods you need to have in your class, but is limited in that they need to be last.

**Update**
When calling methods with optional parameters, you can used named parameters like this:

```
void MyMethod(int value, int otherValue = 0, int newValue = 0);

MyMethod(10, newValue: 10); // Here I omitted the otherValue parameter that defaults to 0
```

So optional parameters gives the caller more possibilities.

One last thing. If you use method overloading with one implementation, like this:

```
void MyMethod(int value, int otherValue)
{
   // Do the work
}

void MyMethod(int value)
{
   MyMethod(value, 0); // Do the defaulting by method overloading
}
```

Then when calling 'MyMethod' like this:

```
MyMethod(100);
```

Will result in 2 method calls. But if you use optional parameters there is only one implementation of 'MyMethod' and hence, only one method call.

Comment: is this an important consideration?

Comment: Less code is always better. Less risk of errors and more readable.

Comment: you can use named parameter in conjunction with optional parameter to avoid having to define the optional parameter around the end of the code. See my post below.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I have also added that to my post

Answer (score 4):

What about a 3rd option: pass an instance of a class with properties corresponding to various "optional parameters".

This provides the same benefit as named and optional parameters, but I feel that this is often much clearer.  It gives you an opportunity to logically group parameters if necessary (i.e. with composition) and encapsulate some basic validation as well.

Also, if you expect clients that consume your methods to do any kind of metaprogramming (such as building linq expressions involving your methods), I think that keeping the method signature simple has its advantages.

Comment: Someone downvoted you, presumably for not answering the question. But I think this is a useful observation nonetheless so +1. Grouping parameters into objects is a refactoring that isn't performed often enough.

Answer (score 4):

A good place to use optional parameter is **WCF** since it does not support method overloading.

Answer (score 3):

This is not really an answer to the original question, but rather a comment on @NileshGule's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3317695/306074), but:

a) I don't have enough reputation points to comment

b) Multiple lines of code is quite hard to read in comments

Nilesh Gule wrote:

> One benefit of using optional parameters is that you need not have to do a conditional check in your methods like if a string was null or empty if one of the input parameter was a string. As there would be a default value assigned to the optional parameter, the defensive coding will be reduced to a great extent.

This is actually incorrect, you still have to check for nulls:

```
void DoSomething(string value = "") // Unfortunately string.Empty is not a compile-time constant and cannot be used as default value
{
  if(value == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException();
}

DoSomething(); // OK, will use default value of ""
DoSomething(null); // Will throw
```

If you supply a null string reference, it will not be replaced by the default value. So you still need to check the input parameters for nulls.

Answer (score 2):

To address your first question,

> why do most MSDN library classes use
>   overloading instead of optional
>   parameters?

It is for backward compatibility.

When you open a C# 2, 3.0 or 3.5 project in VS2010, it is automatically upgraded.

Just imagine the inconvenience it would create if each of the overloads used in the project had to be converted to match the corresponding optional parameter declaration.

Besides, as the saying goes, "why fix what is not broken?". It is not necessary to replace overloads that already work with new implementations.

Answer (score 1):

One benefit of using optional parameters is that you need not have to do a conditional check in your methods like if a string was null or empty if one of the input parameter was a string. As there would be a default value assigned to the optional parameter, the defensive coding will be reduced to a great extent.

Named parameters give the flexibility of passing parameter values in any order.

Comment: You still need to check for nulls when using optional parameters, please see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10154303/306074).

Comment: Guard clauses will increase in case of optional parameters if decision making is required.